# Aliases, templated functions and specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I should start by saying that my knowledge of C++ is pretty limited. I have some understanding of templates and specialization, but I'm by no means an experienced C++ programmer. For example I've today learnt about "aliases" which are not quite the same as "typedefs" and this is completely news to me.

I've been reading up a bit on alias template functions, but I have to admit that I find most examples very cryptic, so I've come up with a very simple use case, see below.

```
#include <iostream>

// A fictitious 24-bit type, that can be manipulated like any other type but can be distinguished from the underlying 32-bit type
using int24_t = int32_t; 

template<typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
  std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
}

template<>
void foo<int24_t>(int24_t x)
{
  std::cout << "24-bit specialization - x = " << x << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
  foo<int16_t>(0);
  foo<int24_t>(1);
  foo<int32_t>(2); // Indistinguishable from 24-bit
}
```

Is it possible to do what I want, i.e. have a specialization of foo<int24_t> but also have a general purpose implementation of foo<int32_t> ?

Comment: `int24_t` and `int32_t` are the same type in your example. You just have two different names for the same type. You can't have multiple specializations for the same type.

Comment: What you are calling an "alias template functions" is a specialized template function.  The `using int24_t = int32_t;` is an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've made an alias (using `typedef` or `using`) that alias is indistinguishable from the original type. You could consider making `int24_t` an [`enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) though.

Example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

enum int24_t : std::int32_t {};

template<typename T>
void foo(T v) {
    std::cout << "base " << v << '\n';
}

template<>
void foo<std::int32_t>(std::int32_t v) {
    std::cout << "int32_t " << v << '\n';
}

template<>
void foo<int24_t>(int24_t v) {
    std::cout << "int24_t " << v << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int24_t a{1};
    std::int32_t b{2};
    unsigned c{3};

    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    foo(c);

    a = static_cast<int24_t>(b); // needed to assign an int32_t to the enum type
    foo(a);
}
```

Output

```
int24_t 1
int32_t 2
base 3
int24_t 2
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot !
In order to distinguish the 24-bit type from the 32-bit one, I had experimented with defining a struct, but the enum really is nicer !
Also static_casts (and other forms of casting) have always been a bit mysterious to me, but at least now (I think) I understand what they do !